# AS3 collision detection is not recognized

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection

I'm quite new to AS3, and I need some help. I'm trying to make a game like Mario. I've made a character which can jump right now, but I've got some problems with collision detection.

I would like my character to jump on a bar, which is placed higher. My collision detection doesn't work at all I gues..

I've made a cirle which has a instance name `mcMain` and I've made a `MovieClip` of it. T also made a rectangle which has a instance name `balkje`, I also made a`MovieClip` of it.

I hope you can tell me what is wrong about my code and what I've to change to make the collision detection work! Thanks a lot!

```
balkje.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, drag);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, drop);

function drag(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    e.target.startDrag();
}

function drop(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    stopDrag();
    if (balkje.hitTestObject(mcMain))
    {
        trace("Collision detected!");
    }
    else
    {
        trace("No collision.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Is `balkje` being dragged arround but the collision not working, or do you have problems moving `balkje`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be using mouseEvent, not keyboard event.
How can you drag with the keyboard?

```
balkje.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
balkje.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);

function drag(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.target.startDrag();
}

function drop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.target.stopDrag();

    if (balkje.hitTestObject(mcMain))
    {
        trace("Collision detected!");
    }
    else
    {
        trace("No collision.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to use a `MouseEvent` to call `startDrag()`. This will work from anywhere in your script.

Comment: @rvmook I didn't state that you have to use a Mouse Event. Try reading posts before marking them down.

Comment: Sure seems like `How can you drag with the keyboard?` implies it, guess I misinterpreted it. Maybe next time try to extend your explenation, or at least don't go acting like punk when someone votes you down.